# how to get source of a page

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

How can I get the source of a page like google, wikipedia or any other using java, c# or any other web language. Also how can I load google or any other site from internet using ajax. I have tried :

```js
function ajaxFunction(){
    var ajaxRequest; // The variable that makes Ajax possible!
    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    // Create a function that will receive data
    // sent from the server and will update
    // div section in the same page.
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('23');
            ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }
    // Now get the value from user and pass it to
    // server script.
    ajaxRequest.open("POST", "https://www.google.com/search", true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null);
}
```

Comment: You can't do that directly.  Learn about the Same-Origin Policy.

Comment: @SLaks is right, you must read something about [Same-Origin Policy](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Answer (score -1):

You can use HttpRequest and HttpResponse , please do let me know if you need code to get page content of given URL